# How does PHP "remote include" work?

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, php-java-bridge

I am wondering how the include ("") works ?

This is my situation. I have apache(php+mysql) running on port 80, but there is a requirement for php-java-bridge. So I installed it on a tomcat-apache (:8080) server.

In my pure apache instance, I have included a file from my tomcat-apache instance.

```
include "http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc";
```

What I would like to know is, will all the java methods/functions now be available to my pure apache instance ?

I guess in other words, how is remote-include different from file-include ?

Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could steal the code that way! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can (not any circumstances) include remote files but if the hosting server interprets that file you will only see the outpu of that file.
(BTW: Retrieve the file and save it on your server then include it and update it frequently.)

Answer (score 0):

My friend you are exactly very good path.

Now try to browse http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/. If you get working than your PHP/Java Bridge installed. First Part is over.

Now make test page in your apache as below

```
<?php
      require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
      echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();
?>
```

and run it. If it works then you can start working with your work. If it not work then you have problem with you php.ini file. Try to make allow_url_once=on in your php.ini.

Now just copy your java jar file in tomcat /webapps/JavaBridge/WEB-INF/lib/ folder and Just always put following line in your page where ever you want java to work

```
require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
$yourObj = Javav("your java class");
$yourObj->yourMethod();
$yourObj->setProperty("xxx");
```

Hope this can help you out.

IF you have still any problem get back.